# GNU Radio, debian compilation error

Tags: linux, gcc, building, gnuradio

have problem when am trying to compile gnuradio 3.6.5 on the latest debian version (8.3).

My gcc version output :

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
```

The make error :

```
[  1%] Built target volk
[  1%] Built target test_all
[  1%] Built target volk_profile
[  1%] Built target doxygen_target
[  2%] Built target gruel
[  2%] Built target test_gruel
[  2%] Built target pmt_generated
[  2%] Built target _pmt_swig_doc_tag
[  2%] Built target pmt_swig_swig_doc
[  2%] Built target _pmt_swig_swig_tag
[  2%] Built target _pmt_swig
[  3%] Built target pygen_gruel_src_swig_8de72
[  3%] Built target pygen_gruel_src_python_31e89
[  3%] Built target pygen_gruel_src_python_d3a1d
[ 30%] Built target gnuradio-core
[ 30%] Built target gnuradio-config-info
[ 31%] Built target gr_core_rstest
[ 33%] Built target test-gnuradio-core
Linking CXX executable benchmark_dotprod_ccc
../lib/libtest-gnuradio-core.so: référence indéfinie vers « gr_reverse(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&) »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gnuradio-core/src/tests/CMakeFiles/benchmark_dotprod_ccc.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'gnuradio-core/src/tests/benchmark_dotprod_ccc' failed
make[2]: *** [gnuradio-core/src/tests/benchmark_dotprod_ccc] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1111: recipe for target 'gnuradio-core/src/tests/CMakeFiles/benchmark_dotprod_ccc.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [gnuradio-core/src/tests/CMakeFiles/benchmark_dotprod_ccc.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Same error after uninstall all old gnuradio libs and binary.(--purge)

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object gnuradio-core/src/lib/CMakeFiles/test-gnuradio-core.dir/bug_work_around_6.cc.o
Linking CXX shared library libtest-gnuradio-core.so
[ 33%] Built target test-gnuradio-core
Scanning dependencies of target benchmark_dotprod_ccc
[ 33%] Building CXX object gnuradio-core/src/tests/CMakeFiles/benchmark_dotprod_ccc.dir/benchmark_dotprod_ccc.cc.o
Linking CXX executable benchmark_dotprod_ccc
../lib/libtest-gnuradio-core.so: référence indéfinie vers « gr_reverse(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&) »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gnuradio-core/src/tests/CMakeFiles/benchmark_dotprod_ccc.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'gnuradio-core/src/tests/benchmark_dotprod_ccc' failed
make[2]: *** [gnuradio-core/src/tests/benchmark_dotprod_ccc] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1111: recipe for target 'gnuradio-core/src/tests/CMakeFiles/benchmark_dotprod_ccc.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [gnuradio-core/src/tests/CMakeFiles/benchmark_dotprod_ccc.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: GNU Radio is C++, not C. Removed the [tag:C], but added [tag:building].

Comment: Are you sure you need GNU Radio 3.6.5? It's only necessary for old legacy code. Newer GNU Radio 3.7.* has a bit of a different API, but is much nicer to use!

Comment: I need 3.6.5 for osmocom-tetra

Comment: Don't do that. Use Osmocom-tetra's `gr3.7` branch, which uses GNU Radio 3.7, and hence is not dead.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, the solution work perfectly ;)

Comment: Please don't post info as answers, but please also don't add answers to questions. I made an answer out of your "solved this by..." edit, so please accept that, or add an answer of your own explaining how you solved that (that would be even better!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote:

> Solved by using GNURadio 3.7.5 + gr3.7 branch of osmotetra.

You shouldn't be using GNU Radio pre-3.7 if you don't have to; since osmo-tetra has a gr3.7 branch, which works with latest GNU Radio, go for that.

Answer (score 0):

This typically is a problem with a different version of GNU Radio that's already installed on your system. So make sure to `apt-get remove gnuradio` beforehand.

Comment: I have full install old version of gnuradio and all libs. Same error :